# How does this show an error?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import os
mGui = tk.Tk()
mGui.geometry("300x300")
mGui.title("YourBowlingSpeed")
mlabel1 = Label (text = "my label")
mlabel1.place (x = 50,y = 150)
```

I changed my habits of importing with * but this doesn't work it shows me an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Projects\YorBowlingSpeed-.py", line 7, in 
    mlabel1 = Label (text = "mylabel")
NameError: name 'Label' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You haven't directly imported the class `Label` into the global namespace, you have only imported the module. To reference it, you have to do:

```
tk.Label(text = "my label")
```

Or, you can import the class:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
```

---

Although I've never worked with Tkinter, I've commonly seen the syntax:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Which imports every class and thus you don't need to put the `tk.` behind class names. Note that this can be risky as if you have a variable called `Label` already, it will be overridden.

Comment: Gah, do not mention the horrid `from tkinter import *` /rant  +1 for the correct answer up top :)

Comment: So for every class i will have to write tk......   but why in my code i wrote mGui = tk.Tk() so shouldnt it be mGui....?

Comment: Right - whenever you want access to a tkinter name, you need to start with `tk.`.  It'll take a bit of work to go through your code and add all the `tk.`'s, but it's worth it.  It avoids the namespace clutter, and it makes your code much more readable - if you or someone else is reading your code, and you're not super familiar with the tkinter API, then it's easy to tell which references come from tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you're using

```
import tkinter as tk
```

You need to reference `tk` to create `tkinter` widgets, so instead of

```
mlabel1 = Label (text = "my label")
```

use

```
mlabel1 = tk.Label (text = "my label")
#         ^^^
```

Glad you switched to this pattern!  Now anyone reading your code instantly knows that `Label` is a function from `tkinter`.  It's unambiguous, easy to read, isn't causing namespace collisions, and makes it easier to maintain the code.

Comment: Thanks got it but cant i do mGui.Label because i put mGui = tk.Tk()?

Comment: Nope - `mGui` is a reference to a `tk.Tk` object, and `Label` belongs to `tk`, not `tk.Tk`.